# Best practice to update dataframe columns with multiple conditions and joins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["SAP       ", 1, 'CHANGE_NEEDED', 10, 11],
                       ["SAP123", 1, 'CORRECT_VALUE', 10, 11],
                       ["NOTSAP123", 1, 'INCORRECT_VALUE', 10, 11],
                       ["NOTSAP456", 1, 'INCORRECT_VALUE', 10, 11]],
                      columns = ["RCD_ORIG_CD", "VEN_ID", "VLC_VEN_ID", "CNTRY_CD", "CO_CD",])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["SAP_CORRECT_VALUE", 1, 'CORRECT_VALUE', 12, 13],
                        ["SAB123",1, "THIS_WONT_BE_USED", 12,13],
                        ["NOTSAP123", 1, 'CORRECT_VALUE', 10, 11],
                        ["NOTSAP457", 1, 'INCORRECT_VALUE', 10, 11]],
                        columns = ["RCD_ORIG_CD", "VEN_ID", "VLC_VEN_ID", "CNTRY_CD", "CO_CD",])
```

```
df1:
  RCD_ORIG_CD  VEN_ID       VLC_VEN_ID  CNTRY_CD  CO_CD
0  SAP              1    CHANGE_NEEDED        10     11
1      SAP123       1    CORRECT_VALUE        10     11
2   NOTSAP123       1  INCORRECT_VALUE        10     11
3   NOTSAP456       1  INCORRECT_VALUE        10     11
```

```
df2:
         RCD_ORIG_CD  VEN_ID         VLC_VEN_ID  CNTRY_CD  CO_CD
0  SAP_CORRECT_VALUE       1      CORRECT_VALUE        12     13
1             SAB123       1  THIS_WONT_BE_USED        12     13
2          NOTSAP123       1      CORRECT_VALUE        10     11
3          NOTSAP457       1    INCORRECT_VALUE        10     11
```

I want to update the records of df1 based on the conditions below (pseudocode-ish for easier understanding). **You can imagine this logic as it needs to be applied for all the records in df1 one by one (obviously that would be really slow):**

```
if df1["RCD_ORIG_CD"].str[:3] == "SAP":
    if df1["VEN_ID"] == df["VEN_ID"] and df2["RCD_ORIG_CD"].str[:3] == "SAP":
        df1["VLC_VEN_ID"] = df2["VLC_VEN_ID"]
        if df1["RCD_ORIG_CD"] == "SAP    ":
            df1["RCD_ORIG_CD"] = df2["RCD_ORIG_CD"]
    else:
        df1["VLC_VEN_ID"] = "        "
elif df1["RCD_ORIG_CD] == df2["RCD_ORIG_CD"] and df1["CNTRY_CD"] == df2["CNTRY_CD"] and
     df1["CO_CD"] == df2["CO_CD"] and df1["VEN_ID"] == df2["VEN_ID"]:
    df1["VLC_VEN_ID"] = df2["VLC_VEN_ID"]
else:
    df1["VLC_VEN_ID"] = "        "
```

I am curious what would be the best practice for this using pandas. What I was thinking about as possible options:

1. joining the 2 dataframes based on different parts of the above conditions. Like a left join on VEN_ID, then updating the VLC_VEN_ID column when different conditions met.
2. actually going record by record with iterrows().

This is not a question which expects a snippet of code as an answer (obviously it is also welcome if you want to), more like an explanation of how a problem like this should be approached.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas that can help:

- Joining `df1` and `df2` would definitely be the preferred way here. Using `df1.merge(df2, on=['RCD_ORIG_CD', 'VEN_ID', 'VLC_VEN_ID'], ...)` (or similar) is clearer and more error-prone than matching them manually column-by-column.
- If different parts of the input dataframe require different processing, you can split them and later `pd.concat` them together.
- You can also conditionally create columns in a vectorized fashion using `np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`, or similar pandas methods (`.where()` or `.mask()`)

A combination of these should be both more performant and easier to read.